# How to use Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I understand that Google Drive APIs can be used for developing apps that can connect to Drive and exploit the features of RealTime API, CRUD Operations on documents, etc.
All the tutorial documents teach about a sample app that can be developed tt connect to Drive.

I have been researching for a while and not able to find if I can get the data about the Documents, Spreadsheets, etc. native to the Drive app from Google. I am trying to build a web app that displays changes/notifications about the resources put on Google Drive. Is it possible to get access to that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There is an important difference between Docs and Spreadsheets. For Docs you must download the complete doc to your application to see the contents. The doc will be converted to say HTML as part of the process. For spreadsheets, you can use the Spreadsheet API to read individual rows or cells. You can of course also use the Drive API to download the full spreadsheet.

You should also research the changes feed (poll), channels (push) and revisions feed if you are specifically interested in changes.